# How do I launch the soft keyboard after "Cancel" button is clicked in DialogFragment?

Tags: android, view, onclick, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

Fragment.java file:

```
....
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skyfrag_layout, container, false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Delete skycard");
    Button btnCancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });
...
```

I tried each of the below in the onClick function but neither worked.

1) getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

2)InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to show the keyboard again because you have a widget that needs editing once your dialog is closed.

Have you tried calling `showSoftInputFromInputMethod (IBinder token, int flags)` instead of `toggleSoftInputFromWindow` ? See the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#showSoftInputFromInputMethod(android.os.IBinder,%20int)).
(Note: the IBinder can be obtained by yourView.getWindowToken())

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  When the dialog is closed I am trying to return to an EditText on the main UI screen.  I tried your suggestion but Android Studio cannot resolve "getSystemService.  Here is what I tried based on your comment:

public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm2 =
                        (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm2.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(v.getWindowToken(),0); ...

Comment: Are you inside a fragment when you make that call? If that's the case you need to do getActivity().getSystemService()... Let me know if that helps

Comment: Yes, inside a fragment.  I stumbled upon getActivity() and added it to the imm code and it works perfectly.  Thanks for checking back with your comment, now I know I am on the right track.  Cheers.